# FastPdfKit Shell Script Invocation error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have downloaded a projects from git while opening it from *Xcode 6* giving me These errors

```
FastPdfKit
```

Shell Script Invocation error

Console log
Console log

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

Create universal static library
/Applications/Xcode 6.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool -static /Users/xeemu1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Popboardz-dtuwsutwwdhzqlglwojmwozfwhvo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FastPdfKit.framework/Versions/A/FastPdfKit /Users/xeemu1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Popboardz-dtuwsutwwdhzqlglwojmwozfwhvo/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FastPdfKit.framework/Versions/A/FastPdfKit -o /Users/xeemu1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Popboardz-dtuwsutwwdhzqlglwojmwozfwhvo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FastPdfKit.framework/Versions/A/FastPdfKit.temp
/Users/xeemu1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Popboardz-dtuwsutwwdhzqlglwojmwozfwhvo/Build/Intermediates/FastPdfKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FastPdfKit.build/Script-958A819E14027EEE00837C82.sh: line 97: /Applications/Xcode 6.0.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/libtool: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Can you add more information to the question?

Comment: Please check console log,that i have pasted

Answer (score 0):

Just check permissions, it worked to me in the cordova/phonegap environment using CLI.